# Azure AD Domain Services only for classic virtual networks?

Tags: azure, networking, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I used the new Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com) to create a Virtual network and created 2 Virtual machines that are connected via that Virtual network.

However, when I want to add an Active Directory resource, it redirects me to the old Azure portal (manage.windowsazure.com), and enabling Domain Services for this Active Directory is possible, but it only allows me to choose from the classic virtual networks (i.e. the ones created with the old Azure portal) - my newly created Virtual network does not appear here.

Is there any way to enable AD Domain Services for the new Virtual networks?
Or, alternatively, perhaps to link my 2 Virtual machines to a classic virtual network?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can enable Azure AD domain services only with classic virtual networks. [Discussed here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-overview/#comments].

However, [you can connect the VNet your VM belong to a classic VNet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-arm-asm-s2s/).

Comment: still appears to be the case :-(